# using variables from a private class in a main function

Tags: java, function, hashmap

I have a private class with 2 variables that I need to use in a for loop in my main function to output. I can't figure out how to use those 2 variables.

this is a for loop in my main function

```
for(String str : uaCount.keySet())
    {
        String [] arr = str.split("|", 2);
        String s1 = arr[0];
        String s2 = arr[1];


        //what I want to do here is something like :
            // average = keySet.sumTime / keySet.occurences;

        System.out.println(s1 + "--->" + s2 + "Average = " + average + "seconds" );
    }
```

here's my private function

```
private class NumberHolder
{
    public int occurences;
    public int sumTime;

}
```

Comment: look into encapsulation http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm you need get and set methods for the values in order to access them outside of the class, otherwise make them public

Comment: @KPZ even if he provides public getters, it won't be of any use as the class is private.

Comment: so what If I made the class public? It isn't completely necessary to have it private and it would make things easier im assuming

Comment: @user2007843 yes if you make the class public, then you just create getters for the two instances of your class, and then create an object of that class to call the getters methods on, which returns the values of your fields.

Answer (score 0):

Your fields occurences and sumTime are public so you can access them directly from outside the NumberHolder class, howevever they are not static, so you'll need an instance of that class:

```
NumberHolder nh = new NumberHolder();
nh.occurances = 20;
nh.sumTime = 30;

//etc...
```

Since ther class is private, it can only be accessed from the containing class:

```
public class ContainingClass {

     private class OtherClass { //can be seen from ContainingClass but nowhere else
         public int otherField; 
     }
}
```